# Appended content is not displayed. Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I make an `ajax` request and append the content (JSON array) of this request to an `HTML` element in order to display it. 
The case flow is the following: ajax request every 5 secs -> append every item to HTML element -> display them. 
 The elements are displayed in a kind of carousel. 
Here is the code I use:

Ajax call:

```
var fetchMessages = function(config) {
    setInterval(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: config.url,
            success: function (query_result, status) {
                displayMessage(query_result);
            },
            error: function (_, status) {
                console.log(status);
            }
        });

    }, 5000);
};
```

The `displayMessage()` which will create a div from every JSON item and append this div to an HTML element.

```
var displayMessage = function(messages) {

    messages.forEach(function(message) {

        // Create the new div.
        var container = $(document.createElement('div'));
        container.addClass('text-center block');

        // Assemble all the stuff. (item created before)
        container.append(<all the stuff>)

        // Get the corresponding HTML element and append the newly created div.
        var sliding_divs_bloc = $('#messages_divs');
        sliding_divs_bloc.append(container);

        // See facts below
        console.log('Appended: '+message.raw);

    });

    slide(messages.length);

};
```

And finally, the `slide()` method, which will slide the divs

```
var slide = function(nbMessages){

    // Only if there is > 1 message, slide them:
    if(nbMessages > 1){
       setTimeout(function(){
              $box.animate({ // Defined above
                  scrollLeft: '+=' + $box.width()
              }, 2000);
          }
       }, 50000);
    }
}
```

So, this workflow works perfectly when I refresh manually the page. Meaning that if the JSON array contained 3 items, these 3 items will be correctly displayed 
 
**However**, when I dynamically populate my JSON array, the newly item from this JSON array is not shown (unless I manually refresh the page). 
 
**Facts**:

1. I am sure the item detected, because I can print it wit `console.log(message.raw)` in `displayMessage()`
2. I am sure there is a new message because `nbMessages` increments as soon as the new message is detected.

Considering all of this, why doesn't my code display all the messages (item from JSON array) following the ajax call, even though I am sure it is there, and that it works when I refresh the page manually?

**Edit** 
Solved with the help from Rory. Added `$('#messages_divs').empty();` before appending all the stuff.

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? Have you inspected the DOM to see if the content is created but hidden?

Comment: This looks suspicious: `container.append(<all the stuff>)`. Is `<all the stuff>` HTML element(s)?

Comment: On a side note: instead of `setInterval` it would be better to use `setTimeout` and call the `fetchMessages` function after receiving the server response

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Indeed, when I inspect the DOM, the element is created. **BUT** never cleaned (so, if the request returned 2 messages, I will have 2 new divs appended to the ones already created.) So the number of divs will grow infinetely ...

Comment: @strah: Why use `setTimeout()` instead of `setInterval()``?

Comment: 1. Because `setInterval` is 'dumb'. 2. because the AJAX request may take longer than expected (even longer than 5 sec) and then your app will behave in unexpected way. Also check this [article why `setInterval` is evil](http://reallifejs.com/brainchunks/repeated-events-timeout-or-interval/) :-)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan. Solved with your help. I `.empty()` everything before :)

Comment: You can also just use `.html()` instead of `.append()`. It replaces instead of adding.